# what should be auto-loaded in emacs libraries?

Tags: emacs

Emacs allows you to "autoload" functions with little cookies like ;;;###autoload

Is there any consensus on what should be autoloaded though? For example, does it make sense to autoload every interactive function in a module (suppose there are a lot of them, e.g. 50)? Or, does it make sense to only autoload the "main" ones.

Comment: Are you asking for an opinion of which should be loaded? Or are you asking an opinion about whether there is a consensus somewhere? Either way, the question is primarily opinion-based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only autoload the "main" ones. For example, `python-mode.el` only has a few occurances of autoload:

```
;;;###autoload
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist (cons (purecopy "\\.py\\'")  'python-mode))
;;;###autoload
(add-to-list 'interpreter-mode-alist (cons (purecopy "python[0-9.]*") 'python-mode))
--
;;;###autoload
(defun run-python (cmd &optional dedicated show)
--
;;;###autoload
(define-derived-mode python-mode prog-mode "Python"
```

Only the "entry" functions are autoloaded. The dozens of helper functions are only needed once you're already in `python-mode`.

Comment: Thanks. What about libraries that just provide functions? E.g. should all the interactive functions get automated?

Comment: Yes, most interactive functions should be autoloaded, or else `M-x` won't be able to find them. For example, `M-x man`, `M-x shell`, `M-x ido-find-file` are all autoloaded. But all of the interactive python-* functions are not autoloaded.

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible scenarios here, and the answer will depend on which one you are working with.

The simple and obvious situation is with a library with a lot of interactive functions but only a few "main" entry points.  The version control modes for Emacs are good examples -- there are many ways to interact with the version control back end, but the first step will usually happen when you check out a piece of code from version control, or want to examine what changes you have made in order to start committing.  So these are the main entry points, and the others will be useful only when you start one of these operations (at least in the typical case).

A somewhat likely but unfortunate scenario would be a "module" which really is many small modules who want to be modules of their own.  If internal cohesion is weak, maybe you should think about moving some parts of the code into separate, smaller libraries.  (There are Emacs libraries which ship with the distribution which fit this description.)

If you really have a complex problem which requires a lot of different entry points, perhaps in fact you do want to expose them all.  Grasping a bit at straws here, I think of e.g. a statistics package -- there are many, many methods to choose from, and you don't know in advance which one will make sense for each scenario.  (Typically this sort of behemoth package will require at least a Bachelor's degree in the subject matter to operate properly, though!)